# Looking for a Reader Writer Lock that works with async/await

Tags: .net, multitasking

I am porting an old application to .NET core.  I need a reader writer lock (many read operations, occasional write operations).  My old code was heavily multithreaded, so the old ReaderWriterLock worked just great.  The new code is Task based, so I'm trying to embrace the async/await pattern.

Which brings me to my need for locking primitives.  The old locking primitives only works when you wait on a single thread.  There's a SemaphoreSlim that's task-aware, but I don't see how this can be used for a Reader Writer lock.

I found this: [AsyncReaderWriterLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asyncreaderwriterlock?view=visualstudiosdk-2019), but I can't find any examples of usage or anyone who seems to be using it.  I don't want to use Stephen Cleary's library if I can use something from Microsoft.  So, what's the story here?  Is there a .NET multi-tasking primitive that supports reader writer locking?  Is there a reason I should avoid using AsyncReaderWriterLock?  Has anyone seen an example of it working?

Comment: There's also https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading on Github.

Comment: specifically [`AsyncReaderWriterLock`](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/AsyncReaderWriterLock.cs) (/cc @xxbbcc)

Comment: Got it.  It appears to be the same library I referenced, but where can I find some examples of usage?

Comment: Note: This is part of Visual Studio `The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading namespace contains APIs for use in Visual Studio SDK projects. You should use these APIs for asynchronous programming in Visual Studio. Doing so helps you avoid deadlocks`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I don't want to use Stephen Cleary's library if I can use something from Microsoft.

Me, either.

> So, what's the story here?

The [VS-Threading library](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading) has a bit of history. It was originally part of the VS-SDK and intended for (and only licensed for) VS extensions. That didn't stop people from finding it and distributing it with their own apps, which I recommended against a few times. These days it's spun off into its own project, available on NuGet, and licensed MIT. So I think it's fine to use these days. But that's the history and I think the history is why it hasn't been widely adopted.

> Is there a .NET multi-tasking primitive that supports reader writer locking?

Not as a part of the framework (at least, not yet). There's [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx), [VS-Threading](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading), and [roll-your-own](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-7-asyncreaderwriterlock/). I'm not sure where VS-Threading exists in terms of Microsoft support - i.e., is it maintained by a particular team? I do see Andrew Arnott and Sam Harwell on recent commits, and they are both geniuses in this area, so I'd say it's in good hands for now. I'm just not sure how official of a Microsoft project it is.

> Is there a reason I should avoid using AsyncReaderWriterLock?

Absolutely. I'm generally against reader/writer locks. The reason is that a lot of developers think "some of my code reads, and some of my code writes, and so I need a RWL", when this is not the case. There's additional requirements: the reads must vastly outnumber the writes, and the reads must at least threaten to overwhelm the writes. If those additional requirements aren't met, then a simple lock works just fine. This is especially the case with asynchronous code; it's not common to hold a lock while doing I/O.

> Has anyone seen an example of it working?

Actually, I haven't, which is kind of funny. But looking at [the source](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/218ab77a6126819c3a5ba256b6ee5f19b987672d/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/AsyncReaderWriterLock.cs), I'd say call `await ReadLockAsync`/`await WriteLockAsync` and then dispose the result value to release the lock. E.g.:

```
using (var releaser = await arwl.ReadLockAsync())
{
  ... // code using await
}
```

AsyncEx and the roll-your-own approach have the same usage.

Comment: 1.) Thank you for the objective analysis of the multi-tasking primitive landscape. 2.) Your usage is correct.  I found an example in the 'Issues' section of the GitHub site. 3.) I agree with you about support.  The fact that S. Harwell is contributing it tells me there must be some respectable community behind the package.

Comment: Can you use this in ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? It's in the VisualStudio namespace! `The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading namespace contains APIs for use in Visual Studio SDK projects.` That seems a good enough reason not to use it.

Comment: It took me a bit to notice the user and realize the irony in the first few lines.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but..

I had to deal with this also. And all solutions are using Tasks instead of a ValueTask in combination with an IDisposable releaser. (so you always have to await it)
I'd rather try to get the lock without any awaiting if it isn't needed. So I came up with a different approach by passing a function to it which will be executed inside the lock.

A ReadersWriterLock Async which returns a ValueTask. So when the lock was taken directly, you don't have to await it.

This library will handle the locks in order they are requested. It also supports continuing on the SynchronizationContext it was initiated on. (useful for UI threads)

I agree on **"This is especially the case with asynchronous code; it's not common to hold a lock while doing I/O."**

*The thing is, you can use async code to wait until the code in the lock has been executed and await it if needed. This doesn't mean the code within the lock have to be async.*

---

Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rwl = new AsyncReadersWriterLock();

        Console.WriteLine("* Example 1");

        // run example 1
        var result1 = Example1(rwl);

        if (!result1.IsCompleted)
            await result1;

        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.WriteLine("* Example 2");

        // run example 2
        var result2 = Example2(rwl);

        if (!result2.IsCompleted)
            await result2;
    }
```

---

```
    private static async ValueTask Example1(AsyncReadersWriterLock rwl)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before calling UseReaderAsync");
        var result = rwl.UseReaderAsync(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reader start");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Reader end");
        });
        Console.WriteLine("After calling UseReaderAsync");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        if (!result.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("result.IsCompleted == false, awaiting");
            await result;
            Console.WriteLine("await finished");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("result.IsCompleted == true, no await is used");
    }
```

---

```
    private static async ValueTask Example2(AsyncReadersWriterLock rwl)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before calling UseReaderAsync");
        var result = rwl.UseReaderAsync(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reader start");
            // no async is used
            //await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Reader end");
        });
        Console.WriteLine("After calling UseReaderAsync");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        if (!result.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("result.IsCompleted == false, awaiting");
            await result;
            Console.WriteLine("await finished");
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("result.IsCompleted == true, no await is used");
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

```
* Example 1
Before calling UseReaderAsync
Reader start
After calling UseReaderAsync

result.IsCompleted == false, awaiting
Reader end
await finished

* Example 2
Before calling UseReaderAsync
Reader start
Reader end
After calling UseReaderAsync

result.IsCompleted == true
```

I'm still working on it. (I don't have much experience with github/creating nuget packages, so any thoughts are welcome)

Package: [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VanLangen.Locking.ReadersWriterLockAsync/)

Source:  [github](https://github.com/jvanlangen/ReadersWriterLockAsync)